# エラーがどうにもできないで困っています。TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Float which has no callable exp method

Tags: python, python3, numpy

エラーメッセージ

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-6078c30c8f23> in <module>
     11         y=np.zeros(10000)
     12         for k in range(10000):
---> 13             y[k]=P(v[k])

<ipython-input-19-6078c30c8f23> in P(v)
      8         v=np.logspace(6,23,10000)
      9         def P(v):
---> 10             return (np.sqrt(3)*q**3*B*sin_pa/(m*c**2))*A(v/v_c)
     11         y=np.zeros(10000)
     12         for k in range(10000):

<ipython-input-8-a3e9f923667c> in A(x)
      5         return F(x)
      6     else:
----> 7         return H(x)

<ipython-input-7-9ec1b5e6fe54> in H(x)
      2     return (4*np.pi/np.sqrt(3)/a)*(x/2)**(1/3)
      3 def H(x):
----> 4     return ((np.pi/2)**(1/2))*(x**(1/2))*(np.exp(-x))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Float which has no callable exp method
```

#### 該当のソースコード

A(x)、sin_pa,m,c,q,は前の段階で関数または数値として定義しています。
A(x)→A(v/v_c)への変換は下のコードが初めてです。

```
from scipy.special import kv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import math
from math import gamma
from sympy import *
import os
```

```py
for i in range(5):
    BmG=10**i
    B=BmG*10**(-6)
    
    for j in range (6):
        g=10**i
        v_c=3*a**2*q*B*sin_pa/(2*m*c*(2*np.pi))
        v=np.logspace(6,23,10000)
        def P(v):
            return (np.sqrt(3)*q**3*B*sin_pa/(m*c**2))*A(v/v_c)
        y=np.zeros(10000)
        for k in range(10000):
            y[k]=P(v[k])
```

また、別の方法として

```py
def P(v):
    v.float()
    return (np.sqrt(3)*q**3*B*sin_pa/(m*c**2))*A(v/v_c)
```

にすると

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6eeb167a8524> in <module>
     12         y=np.zeros(10000)
     13         for k in range(10000):
---> 14             y[k]=P(v[k])

<ipython-input-22-6eeb167a8524> in P(v)
      8         v=np.logspace(6,23,10000)
      9         def P(v):
---> 10             v.float()
     11             return (np.sqrt(3)*q**3*B*sin_pa/(m*c**2))*A(v/v_c)
     12         y=np.zeros(10000)

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'float'
```

となる

別の方法として、A(v/V_c)ではなくA(v)としたらエラーが出てこないで済みます。

```
def P(v):
            return (np.sqrt(3)*q**3*B*sin_pa/(m*c**2))*A(v)
```

A(x)からA(v/v_c)への移行がうまくいっていないのだと思いますが対応をどうすればいいのか...

Answer (score 1):

`v_c` を `int(v_c)` にすることで自己解決しました。